# Create Pandas dataframe from numpy array and use first column of the array as index

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a numpy array (a):

```
array([[ 1. ,  5.1,  3.5,  1.4,  0.2],
[ 1. ,  4.9,  3. ,  1.4,  0.2],
[ 2. ,  4.7,  3.2,  1.3,  0.2],
[ 2. ,  4.6,  3.1,  1.5,  0.2]])
```

I would like to make a pandas dataframe with `values=a`, `columns=A,B,C,D` and `index=` to the first column of my numpy array, finally it should look like this:

```
       A    B    C    D
  1  5.1  3.5  1.4  0.2
  1  4.9  3.0  1.4  0.2
  2  4.7  3.2  1.3  0.2
  2  4.6  3.1  1.5  0.2
```

I am trying this:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(a, index=a[:,0], columns=['A', 'B','C','D'])
```

and I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (5, 4), indices imply (4, 4)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You passed the complete array as the `data` param, you need to slice your array also if you want just 4 columns from the array as the data:

```
In [158]:
df = pd.DataFrame(a[:,1:], index=a[:,0], columns=['A', 'B','C','D'])
df

Out[158]:
     A    B    C    D
1  5.1  3.5  1.4  0.2
1  4.9  3.0  1.4  0.2
2  4.7  3.2  1.3  0.2
2  4.6  3.1  1.5  0.2
```

Also having duplicate values in the index will make filtering/indexing problematic

So here `a[:,1:]` I take all the rows but index from column 1 onwards as desired, see the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)